# Running a loop precisely once per second

Tags: bash, timestamps, sleep

I'm running this loop to check and print some things every second. However, because the calculations take maybe a few hundred milliseconds, the printed time sometimes skip a second.

Is there any way to write such a loop that I am guaranteed to get a printout every second? (Provided, of course, that the calculations in the loop take less than a second :))

```
while true; do
  TIME=$(date +%H:%M:%S)
  # some calculations which take a few hundred milliseconds
  FOO=...
  BAR=...
  printf '%s  %s  %s\n' $TIME $FOO $BAR
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60767/117549

Comment: Note that "**precisely** once per second" is not literally possible in most cases because you are (usually) running in userspace atop a preemptively multitasking kernel which will schedule your code as it sees fit (so that you might not regain control immediately after a sleep ends, for example).  Unless you are writing C code which calls into the `sched(7)` API (POSIX: see [`<sched.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/sched.h.html) and pages linked from there), you basically cannot have real-time guarantees of this form.

Comment: Just to back up what @Kevin said, using sleep() to try and get any sort of **precise** timing is doomed to failure, it only guarantees AT LEAST 1sec of sleep. If you **really** need precise timings you need to look at the system clock (see CLOCK_MONOTONIC) and trigger things based on time-since-last-event + 1s, and make sure you don't trip yourself up by taking >1sec to run, calculating the next time _after_ some operation, etc.

Comment: just going to leave this here http://falsehoodsabouttime.com

Comment: Precisely once a second = use a VCXO. A software-only solution will only get you to "good enough", but not precise.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

To stay a bit closer to the original code, what I do is:

```
while true; do
  sleep 1 &
  ...your stuff here...
  wait # for sleep
done
```

This changes the semantics a little: if your stuff took less than a second, it will simply wait for the full second to pass. However, if your stuff takes longer than a second for any reason, it won't keep spawning even more subprocesses with never any end to it.

So your stuff never runs in parallel, and not in the background, so variables work as expected too.

Note that if you do start additional background tasks as well, you'll have to change the `wait` instruction to only wait for the `sleep` process specifically.

If you need it to be even more accurate, you'll probably just have to sync it to the system clock and sleep ms instead of full seconds.

---

How to sync to system clock? No idea really, stupid attempt:

Default:

```
while sleep 1
do
    date +%N
done
```

Output: 003511461 010510925 016081282 021643477 028504349 03... (keeps growing)

Synced:

```
 while sleep 0.$((1999999999 - 1$(date +%N)))
 do
     date +%N
 done
```

Output: 002648691 001098397 002514348 001293023 001679137 00... (stays same)

Comment: This sleep/wait trick is really clever !

Comment: I'm wondering if all implementations of `sleep` handle fractional seconds?

Comment: @jcaron not all of them. but it works for gnu sleep and busybox sleep so it's not exotic. You could probably do a simple fallback like `sleep 0.9 || sleep 1` as invalid parameter is pretty much the only reason for sleep to ever fail.

Comment: @frostschutz I'd expect `sleep 0.9` to be interpreted as `sleep 0` by naïve implementations (given that's what `atoi` would do). Not sure if that would actually result in an error.

Comment: @jcaron Sure, that's possible... same goes for `date +%N`, it's just not available everywhere, some platforms don't measure time in micro- or even nanoseconds at all and then you just have to live with `sleep 1`. Personally, as long as it works on my modern-day Linux system and less-capable ebook reader, I'm happy with it. If you're targeting an embedded or archaic system you have to adapt it yourself.

Comment: I'm happy to see this question sparked a lot of interest. Your suggestion and answer are very good. Not only does it keep within the second, it also sticks as close to the whole second as possible. Impressive! (PS! On a side note, one must install GNU Coreutils and use `gdate` on macOS to make `date +%N` work.)

Answer (score 30):

If you can restructure your loop into a script / oneliner then the simplest way to do this is with [`watch`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-watch/) and its `precise` option.

You can see the effect with `watch -n 1 sleep 0.5` - it will show seconds counting up, but will occasionally skip over a second. Running it as `watch -n 1 -p sleep 0.5` will output twice per second, every second, and you won't see any skips.

Answer (score 12):

Running the operations in a subshell that runs as a background job would make them not interfere so much with the `sleep`.

```
while true; do
  (
    TIME=$(date +%T)
    # some calculations which take a few hundred milliseconds
    FOO=...
    BAR=...
    printf '%s  %s  %s\n' "$TIME" "$FOO" "$BAR"
  ) &
  sleep 1
done
```

The only time "stolen" from the one second would be the time taken to launch the subshell, so it would eventually skip a second, but hopefully less often than the original code.

If the code in the subshell ends up using *more* than a second, the loop would start to accumulate background jobs and eventually run out of resources.

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative (if you can't use, e.g., `watch -p` as Maelstrom suggests) is [`sleepenh`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/sleepenh) [[manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/sleepenh/sleepenh.1.en.html)], which is designed for this.

Example:

```shell
#!/bin/sh

t=$(sleepenh 0)
while true; do
        date +'sec=%s ns=%N'
        sleep 0.2
        t=$(sleepenh $t 1)
done
```

Note the `sleep 0.2` in there the simulate doing some time-consuming task eating around 200ms. Despite that, the nanoseconds output remain stable (well, by non-realtime OS standards) — it happens once per second:

```
sec=1533663406 ns=840039402
sec=1533663407 ns=840105387
sec=1533663408 ns=840380678
sec=1533663409 ns=840175397
sec=1533663410 ns=840132883
sec=1533663411 ns=840263150
sec=1533663412 ns=840246082
sec=1533663413 ns=840259567
sec=1533663414 ns=840066687
```

That's under 1ms different, and no trend. That's quite good; you should expect bounces of at least 10ms if there is any load on the system — but still no drift over time. I.e., you won't lose a second.

Answer (score 7):

With `zsh`:

```
n=0
typeset -F SECONDS=0
while true; do
  date '+%FT%T.%2N%z'
  ((++n > SECONDS)) && sleep $((n - SECONDS))
done
```

If your sleep doesn't support floating point seconds, you can use `zsh`'s `zselect` instead (after a `zmodload zsh/zselect`):

```
zmodload zsh/zselect
n=0
typeset -F SECONDS=0
while true; do
  date '+%FZ%T.%2N%z'
  ((++n > SECONDS)) && zselect -t $((((n - SECONDS) * 100) | 0))
done
```

Those should not drift as long as the commands in the loop take less than one second to run.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same requirement for a POSIX shell script, where all the helpers (usleep, GNUsleep, sleepenh, ...) are not available.

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54494216

```
#!/bin/sh

get_up()
{
        read -r UP REST </proc/uptime
        export UP=${UP%.*}${UP#*.}
}

wait_till_1sec_is_full()
{
    while true; do
        get_up
        test $((UP-START)) -ge 100 && break
    done
}

while true; do
    get_up; START=$UP

    your_code

    wait_till_1sec_is_full
done
```

Comment: Warning: this implements busy wait always eating one full CPU core for the loop. One could try to test if `perl` is available with `Time::HiRes` and run `usleep()` via perl, instead. Another option would be `python` and `time.usleep`.

Comment: You are right. Using e.g. perl or python, which themselves use time for startup is another problem. The above is scripted with so called shell-builtins. These are native commands, which have nearly 0 execution/run/startup time. But yes, this approach eats up 1 cpu.